# Using Java classes inside Spring @Value('#{SPEL})

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-expression-language

I would like to parse the property value into an custom Object.
Example; i have application.properties; say

```
rules.peakHours.weekday.morning.start=10:15:45
```

And would like to convert that property into java LocalTime object.

```
@Configuration
public class RuleUtils {


    @Value("#{localTime.parse(\"${rules.peakHours.weekday.morning.start}\")}")
    public LocalTime weekDayMorningPeakStart;
```

I have tried the below, but not helping.

```
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("localTime")
//    @EnableConfigurationProperties(LocalTime.class)
    public Class<LocalTime> getLocalTime() {

        return LocalTime.class;
    }
```

Getting below error:

```
 EL1008E: Property or field 'localTime' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
```

I tried web and stackoverflow, but not getting specific answer.
Please help.

Only workaround i know for this is constructor injection; but this will bloat my constructor with many arguments

```
@Configuration
public class RuleUtils {

    public LocalTime weekDayMorningPeakStart;

    public RuleUtils(@Value("${rules.peakHours.weekday.morning.start}") String weekDayMorningPeakStart) {
         this.weekDayMorningPeakStart = LocalTime.parse(weekDayMorningPeakStart);
    }
```

Comment: `@Value("#{localTime.parse` or `@Value("#{LocalTime.parse` ?

Comment: @user404 I have tried both class access and bean access, no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use expression templating to parse into `LocalTime`, like show in the [Expression templating](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-templating) section

```
@Value("#{ T(java.time.LocalTime).parse('${rules.peakHours.weekday.morning.start}')}")
private LocalTime localTime;
```

Comment: After Long time! :)  Great! it worked. It will helpful if you elobarate/hint the necesisty of `T`

Comment: it's a syntax to define the type of object i believe, you can read more info in attached docs